# Is it a bad idea to build redirect flow of OAuth inside an iFrame to reduce app disruption?

Tags: oauth-2.0

To get tokens in OAuth, there is this back and forth with auth provider. screen flickers between sites and Web app looses internal state in the process as well. Plus it could be jarring and confusing for the user.

I've created a solution using hidden iFrame that can get tokens and inform parent site. Users don't see any flickering and app keeps the state as well.

Do you see any issues with this approach and security concerns if any?

Answer (score 0):

By allowing OAuth 2.0 flows to happen in an iframe you are vulnerable to so-called clickjack attacks, see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.1.9

> 4.4.1.9.  Threat: Clickjacking Attack against Authorization
>
> With clickjacking, a malicious site loads the target site in a
> transparent iFrame (see [iFrame]) overlaid on top of a set of dummy
> buttons that are carefully constructed to be placed directly under
> important buttons on the target site.  When a user clicks a visible
> button, they are actually clicking a button (such as an "Authorize"
> button) on the hidden page.
>
> Impact: An attacker can steal a user's authentication credentials
> and    access their resources.
>
> Countermeasures:
>
> o  For newer browsers, avoidance of iFrames during authorization
> can
> be enforced on the server side by using the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header
> (Section 5.2.2.6).
>
> o  For older browsers, JavaScript frame-busting (see
> [Framebusting])
> techniques can be used but may not be effective in all browsers.

For examples see: https://melmanm.github.io/misc/2023/10/01/article10-oauth-clickjacking.html.